# Pagination in Custom Collection magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, collection, product-collection

I am retrieving data from third party as an object,
I am forcefully converting an object into array and collection.

I want to apply pagination with the data, I tried using core pagination logic and setting it into magento 2 but sometimes count doesn't work properly like if no data exists still pagination shows page number dropdown.

Here is the code I have done:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Coupons'));


        if ($this->getCouponBookOrderHistory()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
                'test.news.pager'
            )->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10,15=>15))->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
                $this->getCouponBookOrderHistoryTotal()
            );
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getCouponBookOrderHistory()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
    public function getCouponBookOrderHistory()
    {
        $customerId = $this->customer->getCustomer()->getAcwCustomerId(); 
        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r($customerId);*/
        $result = array();

        $result = $this->coupons->getCouponBooks($customerId);

        //63498
        $result = (array)$result;
        //get values of current page
        $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        //get values of current limit
        $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 10;

        $total = count( $result ); //total items in array    
        $limit = $pageSize; //per page    

        $totalPages = ceil( $total/ $limit ); //calculate total pages
        $page = max($page, 1); //get 1 page when $_GET['page'] <= 0
        $page = min($page, $totalPages); //get last page when $_GET['page'] > $totalPages
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
        if( $offset < 0 ) $offset = 0;
        $result = array_slice( $result, $offset, $limit );

        $master = array();
        array_push($master, $result);
        $collection=$this->_collectionFactory->create();
        // print_r($master); die;

        foreach($master as $row){
            $varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(); 
            $varienObject->setData((array)$row);
            $collection->addItem($varienObject);
        }
        return $collection;
    }
public function getCouponBookOrderHistoryTotal()
    {
        $customerId = $this->customer->getCustomer()->getAcwCustomerId(); 
        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r($customerId);*/
        $result = array();
        $result = $this->coupons->getCouponBooks($customerId);
        //63498


        $result = (array)$result;
        $master = array();
        array_push($master, $result);
        $collection=$this->_collectionFactory->create();
        // print_r($master); die;

        foreach($master as $row){
            $varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(); 
            $varienObject->setData((array)$row);
            $collection->addItem($varienObject);
        }
        return $collection;
    }
```

In my phtml file:

```
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I have created 2 functions `getCouponBookOrderHistoryTotal()` for fetching total proper count so pagination works and other to fetch data from array using array_slice but I am missing something.

Can anyone help me out how can I directly convert this to apply filters to collection, I know 
I tried like this:

```
// $collection->setPageSize($totalPages);
// $collection->setCurPage($page);
```

but still It didnt applied to filters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your below function with below code ?

```
public function getCouponBookOrderHistory()
{
    $customerId = $this->customer->getCustomer()->getAcwCustomerId(); 
    /*echo '<pre>';
    print_r($customerId);*/
    $result = array();

    $result = $this->coupons->getCouponBooks($customerId);

    //63498
    $result = (array)$result;
    //get values of current page
    $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    //get values of current limit
    $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 10;

    $collection=$this->_collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
    $collection->setCurPage($page);
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Hey I am getting data as an object dont I have to convert to collection?

Comment: collection should be in object form always

Comment: didnt worked but!